# OpenCV: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

Please have a look at the following code

**Declaration**

```
vector<vector<Point>> *contours;
vector<vector<Point>> *contoursPoly;

contours = new vector<vector<Point>>();
contoursPoly = new vector<vector<Point>>();
```

**Implementation**

```
//Find contours
findContours(*canny,*contours,*heirarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));

//Draw contours
//drawContours(*current,*contours,-1,Scalar(0,0,255),2);

for(int i=0;i<contours->size();i++)
{
  cv::approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]),contoursPoly[i], 3, true);
}
```

As soon as I run this code I get the error

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Automated  System.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in Automated System.exe
```

This error is coming from this code part of the code

```
cv::approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]),contoursPoly[i], 3, true);
```

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contoursPoly` is a pointer to a vector.

`contoursPoly[i]` treats the pointer to the vector as an array of vectors, and gets the `i`th one.

You want `(*contoursPoly)[i]`, which first dereferences the pointer.  And probably the same for `(*contours)[i]`.

In addition, it is possible that there is no reason to use a pointer-to-vector.

Replace:

```
vector<vector<Point>> *contours;
vector<vector<Point>> *contoursPoly;

contours = new vector<vector<Point>>();
contoursPoly = new vector<vector<Point>>();
```

with

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<vector<Point>> contoursPoly;
```

then, remove the dereference `*`s from:

```
findContours(*canny,*contours,*heirarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));
```

like this:

```
findContours(canny,contours,*heirarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));
```

and change the `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>*` arguments in your functions to `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>&` arguments.  Replace use of `->` on such variables with use of `.`, and remove dereferencing.

Heap based allocation (ie, free store) is something you need to do only sometimes in C++.  Don't do it needlessly.